# Is the profile image of this user appropriate?

Tags: support, profile-page

Can a moderator give a look at [it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/39255/st-pupster)?

I think it is, at least, borderline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user's profile picture has been changed to a generic identicon avatar.

In general, [profile rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/274942) on Stack Exchange are pretty lax. Some things are allowed that would not be allowed in posts, comments, or in chat:

- [Certain obscenities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31197/274942)
- [Self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139190/274942)

[Some cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231334/274942) are really judgment calls, and there are of course [completely unacceptable statements and content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52730/274942). All of this extends to profile pictures.

When in doubt, [**flag a post of the user's for moderator attention**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208551/274942) (or [contact Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/contact), if you really, really want to). A moderator will try to figure out a course of action (see [these guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243285/274942), if you're curious).

---

In the present case, the image contained content that was sexual in nature. There was no nudity, and it's unclear whether or not it would be Not Safe For Work. Like many cases of controversial content in profiles, it was a judgment call as to what to do about it. Working from the guidelines above, the image was removed.

Comment: I can still see it here: https://stackexchange.com/users/9019569/st-pupster?tab=accounts

Comment: @Vincent and you can also see it (and many more) at his Google+ account. But neither has anything to do with Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: @JDługosz If it is inappropriate here, it's inappropriate everywhere on the stack exchange network no?

Comment: @Vincent but we (WB mods) can’t do anything about it there.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for pointing this out.  I've escalated to SE (since we can't edit network profiles).

Comment: @MonicaCellio The image appears to have been replaced with a generic one throughout the network.

Answer (score 7):

Anytime you see something that you find questionable on the site flag it.

If it's an avatar or something posted or linked in a user profile, flag one of the user's posts using a custom mod message explaining what you think the problem is.

If the questionable content is in a question, answer, or comment; flag the content directly using​ a "rude or abusive" flag.

> **rude or abusive** A reasonable person would find this content
>   inappropriate for respectful discourse.